# MySQL update query does not work #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this Query ?

```
UPDATE
    violetta.navi__stop
SET
    violetta.navi__stop.endHour = VB.endHour
FROM
    violetta.navi__stop AS V
INNER JOIN
    violetta_back.navi__stop AS VB
ON V.code = VB.code
```

This code sample works for me on my database:

```
SELECT
V.code, V.endHour
FROM
    violetta.navi__stop AS V
UNIQUE
    violetta_back.navi__stop AS VB
ON V.code = VB.code
```

Comment: MySQL's UPDATE-JOIN syntax differs from most.  `UPDATE table JOIN othertable SET col=val, col=val`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE
    violetta.navi__stop v
INNER JOIN
    violetta_back.navi__stop AS VB
ON V.code = VB.code
SET
    v.endHour = VB.endHour
```